# H2OModelSelectionEstimator deprecated?

Tags: python, h2o, glm

Is the H2OModelSelectionEstimator deprecated? When I run the code

```
from h2o.estimators import H2OModelSelectionEstimator
```

I get the message: ImportError: cannot import name 'H2OModelSelectionEstimator' from 'h2o.estimators'

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
from h2o.estimators.model_selection import H2OModelSelectionEstimator
```

If you can't import it, then you probably don't have the latest version of H2O, so you should [download](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html) it.  [ModelSelection](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/model_selection.html) was just released in 3.36.0.1.